# WordPress adding CSS to frontend through plugin

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce, frontend

Currently looking into adding a bit of CSS to the front-end check-out page, but it doesn't seem to work. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
function css_checkoutpage() {

    if (is_cart() || is_checkout()) {
        echo '
    <style>
       #order_review > table > tbody > tr > td.product-name > dl > dt { float: none !important; }
    </style>
    '
    }
}

add_action( 'init', 'css_checkoutpage' );
```

Comment: where did you put this code?

Comment: Does it work when you add the styles to your style.css?

Comment: I put this code on my functions.php, and it does work when i implement it via inspect element. Haven't tried adding it to style.css yet